# Configure Jboss EAP 6.1 to GZIP Http response

Tags: gzip, http-compression, jboss-eap-6

I tried to compress the Http response by making following changes into the standalone.xml:

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION" value="on"/>
        <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES" value="text/javascript,text/css,text/html,application/json"/>
    </system-properties>
```

But this solution didn't worked. 
I also passed the "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate" header in the request, when I intercepted the http response from server using fiddler it was not compressed.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying the standalone.xml file try to edit the standalone.conf file and add these lines:

- JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on"
- JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES=text/javascript,text/css,text/html"
- JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIN_SIZE=20"

If you are on a unix/linux/macos you can use curl to verify:

```
curl --raw -i -H "Accept-Encoding: \"gzip,deflate\"" -v http://localhost:8020/sarpsa/
```

Check on the reponse your server is returning text/javascript, text/css or text/html:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3M16ifxp2tkkrtoc9ZcKTOCr; Path=/application
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 17:28:34 GMT
```

Otherwise if you are getting some other Content-Type, add it to your list of COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES

Comment: Thanks, those properties worked for me!  (on JBoss EAP 6.4)